# Correlation value has not been initialized on declaration X for activity Y

Tags: workflow, email, state-machine

I have an issue with a SP2010 state machine workflow. The workflow contains two activities, in each of them I'm trying to send mails using the "SendMail" component.

I receive instead the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Correlation value has not been initialized on declaration X for activity Y.

There is definitely a problem with the correlation tokens that I can't figure out. From what I understand I must somehow [use the same correlation token for both "SendMail" tasks even if they are in different activities](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=%7B72C1C85B-1D2D-4A4A-90DE-CA74A7808184%7D&pID=863).

Is that correct? The same correlation token must be used for both? Where do I get that from? I've tried to create the same token with the workflow as the "OwnerActivityName", tried different combinations, nothing...

I don't really get how I must set them up. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by doing the following:

- on the "onWorkflowActivated" component I've set up a correlation token with value "WorkflowToken" (name can be whatever you want) and for the owner activity name I've set the workflow itself.
- for each "SendMail" component I used the same values: "WorkflowToken" for the correlation token and the workflow itself as the owner activity name.